# Generate a separate CSS bundle for IE with Oldie, PostCSS and Webpack

Tags: internet-explorer, webpack, postcss, html-webpack-plugin, postcss-loader

I'm using [Webpack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack), [Extract Text Plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/extract-text-webpack-plugin) and [PostCSS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/postcss) to generate my CSS bundle. I use [Html Webpack Plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-webpack-plugin) to generate an `index.html` file. This is my `webpack.config.js`:

```js
// imports

module.exports = {
  // entry point, etc.
  module: {
    loaders: [
      // other loaders here
      {
        test: /\.scss/,
        loader: debug ? 'style-loader!css-loader!postcss-loader!sass-loader' :
          ExtractTextPlugin.extract({ fallback: 'style-loader', use: 'css-loader!postcss-loader!sass-loader' })
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: debug ? 'style-loader!css-loader!postcss-loader' :
          ExtractTextPlugin.extract({ fallback: 'style-loader', use: 'css-loader!postcss-loader' })
      },
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    // other plugins here
    new ExtractTextPlugin('css/bundle.min.css'),
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      minimize: true
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './dev/index.ejs',
    }),
  ],
};
```

My `postcss.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    require('autoprefixer'),
    require('postcss-object-fit-images'),
    require('oldie')({
      opacity: {
        method: 'copy'
      },
      rgba: {
        method: 'clone'
      }
    })
  ]
};
```

I set RGBA and opacity options to copy the original rules. I tried to do the same with [UnMQ](https://www.npmjs.com/package/postcss-unmq) (postcss to remove media queries for IE) but couldn't find any option to copy the original media queries. I also tried to disable it:

```
require('oldie')({
  opacity: {
    method: 'copy'
  },
  rgba: {
    method: 'clone'
  },
  unmq: {
    disable: true
  }
})
```

Media queries still don't work in Google chrome and Firefox unless I remove oldie from `postcss.config.js`. Now I want to try generating a separate CSS bundle for IE and include it in my `index.html` similar to the example given on the [Oldie](https://github.com/jonathantneal/oldie) website:

```html
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--><link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet"><!--<![endif]-->
<!--[if lte IE 8]><link href="style.oldie.css" rel="stylesheet"><![endif]-->
```

If this is not possible, please suggest another way I can make Oldie work for IE, but not affect media queries for other browsers that support it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a preset.

Create `postcss.config.js` file.

Configure the following to allow transpile:

```
module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        require("postcss-preset-env")
    ]
};
```

However, it won't work unless you've created a browserlist and add your targeted browser(s).

So, create a `.browserslistrc` file.

Configure as follow or whatever:

```
last 2 versions
>1%
ie11
maintained node versions
not dead
```

That should do.

In conclusion, you don't need Oldie. Although, if you want to use the module, Gulp uses it and it's another setup. Webpack simplies a lot already.

Let me know how it goes! :)